# MongoDb-Node:Agregation node-mongo query for chat

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

im new on mongo and want to get data for a chat, let me explain.

i have a colection of messages:

```
_id:id
viewed:boolean
created_at:date
text:String
receiver:ObjectId
emitter:ObjectId
```

i want all the list of messager for a certain emitter and receiver order by the date (like a normal chat)

i have tryed aggregation like this:

```
db.messages.aggregate(
   [

      {
  $lookup: {
     from: "users",
     localField: "emitter",    // field in the orders collection
     foreignField: "_id",  // field in the items collection
     as: "fromItems"
  }
   },


   {
    $match: {

        'emitter':ObjectId("5c8917b4ef9ebf2e608c68dc")
    }
    }      
   ,

    {
         $addFields: {
           ids: { _id: "$_id" } ,
           created: { created_at: "$created_at" }
         }
     },

 {
   $group:
     {
       _id: { tot:["$emitter", "$receiver"] },
       text: { $addToSet:"$text"},

     }
 },
 { 
     $sort: {created_at: 1} 

 }
   ]
)
```

But this gives me an array of messages only of a certain emitter and dont give me the date or the viewed data.
Im really new on mongo and node so if someone can help me with a explain will be great.

Thanks for reading and sory for the bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must include date or the viewed data in `$group` stage.

Try with this.

```
{
 $group:
 {
   _id: { tot:["$emitter", "$receiver"] },
   text: { $addToSet:{text:"$text",created:"$created.created_at"}},
   created_at:{$last:"$created.created_at"}
 }
},
```

Why there is `ids` and need for `tot` fields and `created` as a object ??

Comment: hi thanks , that work, it was usefull to note that i need another schema, so all the messages are part of a chat(because i need in the json my messages to that person to, and in this moment i dont know how many people write to me), and i dont have the chat schema,, so i think what i was triying was imposible to do.
Sory for being so hard to understand what i need